# Spring Boot GraphQL: Expected type to be a GraphQLInputType, but it wasn't

Tags: spring, spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java

I am trying to set up a GraphQL endpoint in Spring Boot, and when I try to run my App, I get the following error:

`Expected type 'Order' to be a GraphQLInputType, but it wasn't!  Was a type only permitted for object types incorrectly used as an input type, or vice-versa?`

Here is my models.graphqls:

```
type Order {
    id: String!
    storeOrderId: String
    connectionId: String
}

type Mutation {
    createOrder(order: Order): Order
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you're trying to use a `type` for an input, which isn't allowed.

`type Order {`

Should be...

`input Order {`

So that the whole thing looks like:

I am trying to set up a GraphQL endpoint in Spring Boot, and when I try to run my App, I get the following error:

`Expected type 'Order' to be a GraphQLInputType, but it wasn't!  Was a type only permitted for object types incorrectly used as an input type, or vice-versa?`

Here is my models.graphqls:

```
input Order {
    id: String!
    storeOrderId: String
    connectionId: String
}

type Mutation {
    createOrder(order: Order): Order
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if it still does't work after use a `input` type, There may be other problems here.

- the input java types should have public getters,
- the input java types should also implement `Serializable` interface